# How can I use Ajax to delay a PHP for loop and echo out PHP on screen?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sqlite

i'm not sure whether Ajax is what I need as i'm rather stumped on where to start, but I'll describe what I would like to happen.

I have a PHP file (lets call it scan.php) that contains a For loop that iterates along an array, which holds details of local files stored in a directory on a PHP. For each item in the array (a path to a file), I would like it (presumably an ajax script?) to call another php file (lets call it info.php) and display whatever that PHP file outputs on screen, with info.php taking the filepath in that index of the array as an argument.

Within that info.php file are various (dynamically generated) divs which inserts a different value into the database depending on which div the user clicks on. When that user clicks on a div, it inserts a value into the database (via an ajax call that i've already got working) and then displays a message (i'm using a javascript window.alert). If that message is a success then the info.php function ends, an we return back to scan.php. Whatever echoed out by info.php is cleared and then the loop iterates round again.

Sorry it's a bit complex but I have no idea where to start. Could anybody give me any hints on how to get started? I've had a look at ajax but frankly I have no idea where to start and whether it's even possible to use ajax to delay the PHP for loop.

This was my script that I thought would display info.php, but it's not echoing anything into the "show" div - or anything at all:

```
    function Search_file(path) {
    $( "#show" ).empty();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "info.php?path="+path,
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });
    $("#show").html(result); 
    request.done(function(data) {
        alert("Next file");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, so you haven't received your result when you are setting your html. You need to move your 'show' code inside the `done` handler like so:

```
function Search_file(path) {
    $("#show").empty();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "info.php?path="+path,
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(data) {
        $("#show").append(result); 
        alert("Next file");
    });
}
```

Comment: OK thanks, but how do I make it wait until i've done whatever I need to do within the output of info.php, before exiting that function and going onto the next iteration of the for loop? This is my php for loop within scan.php: foreach (preg_grep('/^([^.])/',scandir(realpath($row["movies_dir"]))) as $key => $value) {
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  Search_file(".urlencode(pathinfo($value)['filename']).");
</script>";
}

Comment: Hi, unfortunately after moving that line to where you said it should go, it's still not outputting anything.

Comment: I think it's my PHP code that is wrong, as that code in the php for loop isn't even loading a simple window.alert test either.

Comment: Did you get your loop figured out? I updated my example to append to the result instead of clearing and replacing every time. This way you don't have to wait for each iteration of the loop it just appends the responses when they are ready. This is really the whole point of an AJAX call. Also if you think the PHP is relevant to the question you should edit your question, instead of adding the code in the comments.

Comment: I've got it to display OK, but now I can't get the loop (it's now a jquery each loop) to wait for user input before moving onto the next index. See this new question i've created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614646/how-can-i-pause-a-jquery-each-loop-while-waiting-for-user-input