# How can I pause a jQuery .each() loop, while waiting for user input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sqlite

I'm having trouble getting a jQuery `.each loop` to wait for user input, before continuing iterating. 
Here is my code (I've commented with what I would like to happen):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common_components.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider.css">

<?php
include_once 'common_components.php';
$query = $dbh->query("SELECT movies_dir FROM settings");
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo "<title>Movie Scanner</title>";
?>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var retval = "not done";
function EnterManually() {
alert("Entering Data Manually"); //data has been entered manually so exit function & move ontop next index in loop in document.ready.
retval = "done";
}

function insertIntoDB(id,path) {
var request = $.ajax({
url: "update_movie.php?id="+id+"&path="+path,
type: "GET",            
dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function(data) {
if (data == 0) {
alert("Movie Succesfully Inserted"); //data has been entered sucessfully (update movie returns 0) so exit this function & search_file function & move ontop next index in loop in document.ready.
retval = "done";
}
else if (data == 1) {
alert("Unable to insert movie!"); //update_movie.php returns an error (returns 1), so exit this function but DON'T exit search_file function - wait for user to click on another set of details.
retval = "not done";
}
});
}
var files = <?php echo json_encode(preg_grep('/^([^.])/',scandir(realpath($row["movies_dir"]))))?>;
function Search_file(path) {
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","search_file.php?path="+path,false); //load search_file.php with movie
xmlhttp.send(); //send file off
$('#result').empty();   //clear div of content
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; //load output into page
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="result">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.each(files, function(key, value) {
Search_file("<?php echo addslashes(realpath($row["movies_dir"]))?>"+"\\"+value); //iterate to next item in array & run search_file function
});
});

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially, the 'files' variable contains a JSON array of file paths. for each index in the array, the `Search_file function` is run on that path, which should display a list of search results for that file - calling & displaying the `search_file.php` page.

When the user clicks on any of those results in the displayed list, it should attempt to insert (via the `InsertIntoDB` Function, which calls the `update_movie.php` file) a record into the database.

If that insert is successful (`update_movie` returns 0) (or the `EnterManually` function is triggered) then the functions should all exit, and the `.each` loop should move onto the next iteration, starting the whole process off again.

If that insert function is not successful (so `update_movie` will return 1), then nothing should happen - the `.each` loop should not increment. Instead, we should wait for the user to click on another result.

At the moment, I cannot get the `.each` loop to wait until the user has clicked on a result, it just keeps incrementing straight until the last item in the loop.

Comment: There is no wait() in JavaScript so you can not do what you want. You would have to break it up and create a method that iterates when you call the next step.

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

you could just go through the files one at a time.

```
var index = 0;
$("#result").on("click", function(){
    Search_file("<?php echo addslashes(realpath($row["movies_dir"]))?>"+"\\"+files[index]);
    index++;
});
```

the idea is every time you click result's div it will load the next file. I didn't include code to check limit, and things like that.